# Naming convention for a function that analyzes several objects and returns a boolean value

Tags: python, naming-conventions

It is well accepted that assertion functions that check a single value/object have names that start with "is" (`is_valid`, `is_ok`, `is_empty`). I have a function that compares several objects (strings, in my case) and decides whether they are "similar enough". How would you name such a function? My variant is  `are_strings_similar(s1, s2, s3)`, but it looks somewhat awkward.

The code is in Python, BTW

Comment: I'd call it "are_similar" and move on with my life.

Comment: But then I'll have to actually work, instead of "thinking" :-)

Comment: Or go with `check_similarity(s1, s2, s3)` because `are_similar` seems awkward to me too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I would go with is_strings_similar or just is_similar. Why? Because it makes the string search through your code for all assertion functions that much easier. It's code, not a research paper. Improperly conjugated verbs are not the main issue, ease of maintenance is. Most any English speaker can read "is_strings_similar" and parse out the function's purpose. However, no regex parser I'm aware of can search for the different conjugates of the 'to be' verb without additional input from the user.

Comment: Good idea, and you can say is_string_group_similar(), or is_string_set_similar() and still maintain proper english :-)

Answer (score 1):

Totally depends on what certain naming convention do you use. If naming of such functions is not described in it, then name the function as you will. `are_strings_similar` looks just fine for me. It's not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the ideal would be to create a method `similar` and have it accept 2+ iterables as a parameter set ;-)

Personally, I think that the type inclusion makes the name a bit awkward, but this is personal preference. It does not violate any of the [style guidelines](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) as I read them.

It may help clarify *your* thoughts to actually read it out loud.

```
if are_similar_strings("foo","fo","fooo"): #guessing at implementation here.
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
if nearly_equal(s1, s2, s3):
```

or

```
if nearly_the_same(s1, s2, s3):
```

unittest uses assertAlmostEqual, so perhaps

```
if almost_equal(s1, s2, s3):
```